# How to write logback StatusManager data to log file?

Tags: java, logging, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

According to the [logback website](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#statusListener), we can write `StatusManager` data with `StatusListener`.
There is mainly 2 status listener for writing status manager message.

1. OnConsoleStatusListener - Print the message on the console, i.e. on System.out
2. OnErrorConsoleStatusListener - Print the message on the console, i.e. on System.error

But I need to write those `StatusManager` messages to the error log. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since logback does not provide a `StatusListener` implementation to send status messages to a file, you'll need to provide your own implementation of `ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusListener`.
For simplicity, extend `ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase` and override its `getPrintStream()` method to provide a `PrintStream` to a log file.

Then configure logback to use your status listener:

```xml
<statusListener class="yourpackage.YourStatusListener" />
```

Alternatively, you can use the logback-provided `OnConsoleStatusListener` and redirect your program output to a file.